# Piping output of system command to file

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, system

I am working on an assignment where I am required to run system commands and write the output to a file. At the moment I am able to pipe the output using the  `>> output.txt` at runtime but how do I do it automatically in my program without having the user type the piping part. I have tried concatenating it in the `system` function itself while also trying to create a `temp` variable to append it at the beginning of each loop. I haven't worked with C in years and so a task that is relatively easy I am finding hard. Here is my source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*argc holds the number of arguments and argv is an array of string pointers with indifinate size  */

    /*Check to see if no more than 4 arg entered */
    if(argc > 4 && argc > 0) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments. No greater than 4");
        return 0;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    char* temp[128];

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        //strcopy(temp, argv[i]);
    //  printf("%s", temp);
        system(argv[i] >> output.txt);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>>` in this context is not a shell redirect but the C right-shift operator.

The redirection needs to be part of the command sent to `system`.  Also, `temp` needs to be an array of `char`, not an array of `char *`:

```
char temp[128];
sprintf(temp, "%s >> output.txt", argv[1]);
system(temp);
```

Comment: Okay I understand that but I am having issues placing temp in sprintf. I cannot use a char[128] with a *char type. I tried removing the size of the temp char pointer but then I get a seg fault. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You have `temp` declared as an array of pointers instead of an array of `char`.

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you for your explanation!